# Laravel - how to access public folder from JS file

Tags: laravel

I am using the exact same Ajax call in multiple blade templates.

If Ajax fails, I show an error jpg located in `public/images/danger.png`.

When I had my JS in the blade file written inline in `<script>` tags, it was easily accessible as I had blade helpers to access public with:

`{{asset('/images/danger.png')}}`

Yet now, accessing `/public` with:

`http://"+location.host +"/public/images/danger.png`
is impossible.

It would be unDRY to put the **exact same AJAX call** in 12 blades, no need to elaborate why..
How do you guys counter this issue?

Comment: I would just add `<script> window.sharedVariables.errorimage = {{asset('/images/danger.png)}}</script>` in my main template .blade and then use it as a JS global whenever I need to. Not the most elegant solution but unfortunately JS files don't parse blade templates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

remove /public from your route,you can  directly use /images/imgname.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can just use absolute routes in your javascript files. This will however not work if your Laravel application sits in a sub folder.

```
"/public/images/danger.png"
```

Comment: absolute routes is absolutely right. will mark as answer once it allows. thx

Answer (score 0):

just the same as used in html (in blade)
like

```
$('.abc').attr("src", "{{asset('imgs/male_b.svg')}}");
```